# Neural Network outputs

Tags: output, neural-network

I need to develop a neural network and classify the inputs into 3 categories. One of the category is "Don't Know"

Should I train the network using a single output perceptron which categories the training examples as 1,2, or 3? Or should I use a 2 output perceptron and use a binary scheme (01, 10, 00/11) to classify the inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 3 output neurons (one for each class). In the training phase, set output of neuron representing correct class to 1 and all others to 0. Single output with 1 2 and 3 is not optimal because that contains implicit assumtion that classes 2 and 3 are somehow "closer" to each other then 1 and 3. 2 outputs with binary coding is also not good, because in addition to solving classification problem you NN will have to learn binary encoding.

Also, its probably best to use softmax activation on output layer with cross-entropy error function. Softmax will normalize output, so values at each neuron could be interpreted as class probabilities.

Note that "don't know" class in only useful if you have training examples labeled as "don't know". Otherwise, use two output neurons.